# Dapper Many-to-Many Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dapper

I am trying to write a query to get a user in the system with all of his/her roles.  There is a many-to-many relationship between users and roles.  The joiner table is `SystemUserUserRole` with columns `UserId` and `RoleId`.  My models are below:

SystemUser Model

```
[Key]
public int UserId { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(75)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(75)]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(15)]
public string Phone { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(250)]
public string Email { get; set; }

public virtual List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

UserRole Model

```
[Key]
public int RoleId { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(250)]
public string RoleName { get; set; }

public virtual List<SystemUser> SystemUsers { get; set; }
```

I am trying to do something below with no luck.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

```
string query = "SELECT u.*, r.* FROM SystemUser u INNER JOIN SystemUserUserRole ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId INNER JOIN UserRole r on ur.RoleId = r.RoleId WHERE Email = @email AND IsActive = true;";

SystemUser user = con.Query<SystemUser, UserRole, SystemUser>(query, (SystemUser, UserRole) => { SystemUser.UserRoles = UserRole; return SystemUser; }).First();
```

Answer (score 11):

This will work:

In the SystemUser class, add a constructor that initialises the list:

```
public SystemUser()
{
    UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
}
```

Then tell Dapper that for each joined row, the UserRole should be added to the SystemUser.UserRoles:

```
SystemUser user = con.Query<SystemUser, UserRole, SystemUser>(query,
    (SystemUser, UserRole) =>
    {
        SystemUser.UserRoles.Add(UserRole);
        return SystemUser;
    },
    splitOn: "RoleId").First();
```

Note that the final piece is adding the `splitOn` parameter, because Dapper expects identity columns to be named `Id`, otherwise you need to tell it the column name explicitly.

Comment: Could you comment on related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420442/dapper-multi-mapping-not-working-as-expected? I think it is quite similar, but I'm getting an unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing... feel free to comment or post a better solution if there is one.

I had to do three separate queries.  I first grabbed the user object.

```
SystemUser user = con.Query<SystemUser>("SELECT * FROM SystemUser WHERE Email = @email AND IsActive = true", new { email = email }).First();
```

I then grabbed the RoleIds from the joiner table:

```
IEnumerable<int> roleIds = con.Query<int>("SELECT RoleId FROM SystemUserUserRole WHERE UserId = @userId", new { userId = user.UserId });
```

Finally, I updated the user object and pulled all of the roles associated to that user:

```
user.UserRoles = con.Query<UserRole>("SELECT * FROM UserRole WHERE RoleID IN @roleIds", new { roleIds = roleIds }).ToList();
```

Comment: You can try the solution presented here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786514/many-to-many-in-linq-using-dapper/50786918#50786918

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this which worked for me:

```
var result = con.Query<User, Role, User>(query, (u, r) => 
                    { 
                        u.UserRoles.Add(new UserRole{ User = u, Role=r }); 
                        return u; 
                    }, splitOn:"RoleId");
```